# Using JavaScript reflection to invoke a function

Tags: javascript, reflection

I am new to JavaScript and am struggling with how reflection works there.
What I want to do is: Given a String which is the function's name, invoke that function.
E.g. var myString = "myFunctionName()" is given and then I want to invoke myFunctionName() using myString somehow.

Is this possible and how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible if you know the scope/namespace that holds your function. Like `window[myString]()`.

Comment: @hxhzre I want to implement a DAG which has conditions on its edges and I want to store the whole thing in an array. The real usecase would be a wizard. I am not too sure whether that would lead to clean code so I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It all depends on the context in which the function is declared.

For the browser's `window` context:

```js
function test() {
  console.log('Hello world!');
}

const string = 'test';

window[string]();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
function myFunctionName() {
  // do something...
}

var myString = "myFunctionName()";

eval(myString)
```

Comment: You can try that, but be aware of the [risks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).